# Why isn't my Twig replace filter working with craft.request.getUrl()?

Tags: templating, filter

I'm rendering some HTML into a variable. On this HTML I want to replace a value using `craft.request.getUrl()` but the value doesn't seem to get replaced. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
{% set pages %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages') %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
         <a href="{{ entry.url }}" data-url="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endset %}

{{ pages|replace({'data-url="{{ craft.request.getUrl() }}"': 'class="active"'})|raw }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
{{ pages|replace({('data-url="' ~ craft.request.getUrl() ~ '"'): 'class="active"'})|raw }}
```

You were double nesting Twig tags `{{ {{ }} }}`, which is never necessary.  You'll want to use string concatenation instead. Also for dynamic keys in twig you need parentheses.

Comment: `{{ navigation|replace({'data-url="' ~ craft.request.getUrl() ~ '"': 'class="active"'})|raw }}` gives me "A hash key must be followed by a colon (:)" and `{{ navigation|replace({'data-url="' ~ craft.request.getUrl() ~ "': 'class="active"'})|raw }}` gives me error "Unclosed """". Any ideas?

Comment: @naboovalley for dynamic keys in twig you need parentheses, so try `{{ navigation|replace({('data-url="' ~ craft.request.getUrl() ~ '"'): 'class="active"'})|raw }}`

Comment: That did it! :)